# Approximating the solution to a system of 2 oscillatory ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Background**

I have the following system of ODEs:

$f'(t)=\phi-acf(t)g(t)$

$g'(t)=\epsilon acf(t)g(t)-\delta g(t)$,

Setting $f'(t)=0$ and $g'(t)=0$ and solving for $f$ and $g$ reveals that the system exhibits an equilibrium, $(f^*,g^*)$, where $f^*>0$ and $g^*>0$.

The two eigenvalues corresponding to the equilibrium are $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_1)<0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_2)<0$.

Since these eigenvalues are both negative, we know the equilibrium is asymptotically stable.

Further analysis of the eigenvalues reveals that the equilibrium is oscillatory.

**Question**

Is there a way to analytically calculate (or approximate) the amplitude of $f$ and $g$'s oscillations given $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

I am hoping to acquire an analytical expression that describes the amplitude, and how it changes over time due to damping, so that I can approximate the different local minima that $f$ and $g$ achieve as they approach their stable equilibrium.

Comment: A system of two _second_ order ODEs of two _first_ order ODEs? Also, do you mean $\text{Re}(\lambda_{1/2}) < 0$?

Comment: I meant a system of two second order ODEs and I also meant that the real part of the eigenvalues is less than zero. I updated the question with these clarifications; sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Can you include the system of ODEs?

Comment: So, if the eigenvalues have negative real and nonzero complex part, you will see decaying oscillations for the linearized system. IMO, decaying means that there is no "special" amplitude you may calculate, or what do you understand to be "the amplitude"

Comment: @NeitherNor I just mean the amplitude in the absence of damping; although damping is occurring due to the negative eigenvalues, I was wondering if one can calculate the undamped amplitude or the damping coefficient given the eigenvalues?

Comment: Linear oscillatory systems without damping don't have a fixed/special amplitude; however, nonlinear systems might have. It sounds like that you want to modify a nonlinear system to possess a stable limit cycle, a task which has to be well defined to be meaningful. It would really help if you could provide the nonlinear ODEs, and maybe some background why you want the amplitude/ which question the amplitude answers. What you are asking for clearly needs a special interpretation to have a meaningful answer, and yet you do not provide sufficient details and insight for us to guess what you want.

Comment: @NeitherNor Thank you for your response! I updated the question with the equations, as well as a brief explanation as to why I am hoping to calculate/approximate the amplitude

Comment: If the eigenvalues are complex, they are complex-conjugate for a real system. $\lambda_{1,2}=\alpha\pm i\beta$ with $\alpha<0$ as the decay rate and $\beta$ the frequency of the oscillation. The eigenvectors might not be orthogonal, so that the amplitude as Euclidean distance from the equilibrium might not be continuously falling, one would need to use an elliptical norm for that.

Comment: Say the eigenvalues of the system linearized around $f^*, g^*$ are $\lambda_{1,2}=\sigma\pm\omega i$, with $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then, close to $f^*,g^*$, your dynamics are well approximated by $f(t)\approx f^*+A_fe^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t+\phi_f)$ and $g(t)\approx g^*+A_ge^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t+\phi_g)$, whereby the initial amplitudes $A_f$ and $A_g$, as well as the initial phases $\phi_f$ and $\phi_g$, depend on the initial conditions $f(0)$ and $g(0)$. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NeitherNor Is there a book or paper I could read to better understand why this approximation works and to perhaps see a derivation? (Thank you again!)

Comment: @NeitherNor Also, what if the system has three variables (the third being $h(t))$ such that we have a positive equilibrium of $(f^*,g^*,h^*)$? Does the approximation still work?

Comment: No, the approximation becomes $f(t)=f^*+A_fe^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t+\phi_f)+b e^{\lambda_3 t}$, where $\lambda_3$ is the new additional eigenvalue you get since you more have 3 instead of 2 states, and b depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: @NeitherNor Oh, I think I understand; so is $\lambda_3$ the non-complex eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General theory: we linearize the system around the steady state and define $x_1=f-f^*$, $x_2=g-g^*,\ldots$. The linearized system then becomes
$$\frac{d}{dt}x_1=a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\ldots$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}x_2=a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\ldots$$
$$\vdots$$
or, in matrix notation
$$\frac{d}{dt}x=A x.$$
We denote by $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \ldots$ the eigenvalues of $A$. Now, under the assumption that A is diagonizable (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix ), the solution becomes
$$x_1(t)=\bar{z}_{11}e^{\lambda_1 t}+\bar{z}_{12}e^{\lambda_2 t}+\ldots$$
$$x_2(t)=\bar{z}_{21}e^{\lambda_1 t}+\bar{z}_{22}e^{\lambda_2 t}+\ldots$$
whereby the $\bar{z}_{ij}$ are constants which depend on the initial conditions. The individual functions $e^{\lambda_i t}$ are called the $n$ homogenous solutions of the system.

Now, this works independently if your eigenvalues are real or complex. If they are complex, however, the corresponding $\bar{z}_{ij}$ also become complex and everything is ugly. However, we can make the solutions nicer by utilizing that we always get complex conjugated pairs of eigenvalues, e.g. $\lambda_{1,2}=\sigma\pm\omega i$. Using some magic (i.e. Euler's formula and some obscure sin/cos-relationships you can look up on wikipedia), you can then simplify the corresponding homogenous solutions to
$$x_1(t)=A_1e^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t+\phi_1)+\ldots$$
$$x_2(t)=A_2e^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t+\phi_2)+\ldots$$
The stuff which is coming after the $\ldots$ is the same as before, and $A_1$ and $\phi_1$ are just two new constants which depend on the initial conditions which replace $\bar{z}_{11}$ and $\bar{z}_{12}$. Note that this solution is identical to the one before, it's just rewritten to not contain any complex numbers anymore.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is extremely helpful. Just out of curiosity: how does the $be^{\lambda_3t}$ term appear in the case of three variables?

Comment: Well, 3 states imply three eigenvalues. W.l.o.g., assume that $\lambda_{1,2}$ is the complex conjugated pair, which implies that $\lambda_3$ must be real. We start with the general solution $$x_1(t)=\bar{z}_{11}e^{\lambda_1 t}+\bar{z}_{12}e^{\lambda_2 t}+\bar{z}_{13}e^{\lambda_3 t}$$ and then replace the first two terms as explained in the answer and get $$x_1(t)=A_{1}e^{\sigma t}\cos(\omega t +\phi_1)+\bar{z}_{13}e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

Comment: I have one more question: when you say that $z_{13}$ is dependent on initial conditions, what exactly do you mean? Is it the initial amplitude of one of the other variables or?

Comment: You normally know the values of the states at some initial time, usually $t_0=0$, i.e. you know $f(0), g(0),\ldots$. Your solutions will now depend on these values. For example, the position of a car at time $t$ depends on its initial position and speed at time $t=0$. Now: $$x(0)=\bar{z}_{11}+\bar{z}_{21}+\ldots=f(0)-f^*$$. You will get some other equations by plugging in the general solution into the ODEs. Together with the equations above from the ICs, these allow you to solve for the $\bar{z}_{ij}$. For example, for $f(0)=f^*,g(0)=g^*,\ldots$, you find $\bar{z}_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: So if we have three variables, $f(t)$, $g(t)$, and $h(t)$; and we know the values of $f(0)$, $g(0)$, and $h(0)$, then what would the value of $z_{13}$ be? I can post this as a new question if that would be preferred

Comment: Yeah, maybe a new question would be smart. It's essentially just a long and tedious calculation, plugging the solution into the ODEs and ICs, extracting the equalities and finally solving them. I guess there should be a general matrix solution but I don't know it. The point is, to be honest, it's quite boring to do, more calculating than doing math, and I don't like calculating. Sorry...

Comment: No worries at all; thank you for all of the help regarding my original question!

Comment: Is there a book one can read as a reference for your answer to this question? I am hoping to acquire a deeper understanding of the approximation

Comment: I don't think you need a book, it's quite simple. I also don't have a book. But you might read up here: https://math24.net/linear-homogeneous-systems-differential-equations-constant-coefficients.html and https://math24.net/method-eigenvalues-eigenvectors.html . If this is not sufficient, you might however have learned enough keywords to make a Google search for more information.