# Approximating the solution to a system of 3 nonlinear ODEs with the KBM method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

**Background**

I have the following system of ODEs:

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=x\dfrac{q}{Q}-x\dfrac{x+y}{M}\quad$ (Eq. 1)

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}=y(1-\dfrac{q}{Q})(1-c)(1-v)-aq-y\dfrac{q}{Q}v(1-c)-x\dfrac{q}{Q}v\quad$ (Eq. 2)

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=y(1-c)-y\dfrac{x+y}{M}\quad$ (Eq. 3),

where all variables and parameters are positive, $M\gg 0$, and $Q\gg 0$.

Setting these three equations equal to zero and solving for $(x, q, y)$ reveals that the system exhibits an equilibrium, $(x^{*},q^{*},y^{*})$, where $x^{*}>0$, $q^{*}>0$, and $y^{*} >0$. Under certain conditions, this equilibrium exhibits damped oscillations.

**Goal**

I am hoping to approximate the system's solution using the KBM method, which is described in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684594/approximating-the-solution-to-a-system-of-two-odes-with-the-kbm-method/4684849#4684849) post and, most relevantly, in [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02460988) paper. In the latter paper, what is noted is that, to approximate variable $y$'s dynamics, we want a second-order differential equation of the following form:

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+2b\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}+r^2y=\epsilon f^{(1)}\left(y,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)+\epsilon^2 f^{(2)}\left(y,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)+...$ (Eq. 4),

where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, $b \geq 0$, and $r>0$.

**What I have so far**

To acquire the desired second-order ODE, I first took the derivative of Eq. 3 to acquire:

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\dfrac{y\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+((-1+c)M+x+2y)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}}{M}$ (Eq. 5).

To simplify, I then let $Q=M$ and took the limit of Eq. 5 as $M \rightarrow \infty$, which gives:

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t}=-\left((-1+c)\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)$ (Eq. 6).

I then rewrote Eq. 6 as:

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t}+2(c-1)\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}+y(c-1)^2=(c-1)\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}+y(c-1)^2$,

where here $b=(c-1)$, $r=(c-1)$, and $\epsilon=(c-1)$.

**Questions**

Is my approach to acquiring the general form of Eq. 4 valid?

More broadly, how can I proceed to analytically approximate the system's oscillatory solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the limit of $M \to \infty$, Equation 6 demonstrates that $y$ cannot possibly exhibit oscillatory behavior as the solution to that equation is an exponential that grows to infinity for positive $\epsilon$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures Thank you for your response! If I were to acquire a version of Equation 6 that is oscillatory, how should I proceed to carry out the KBM method? The example you shared in my previous email was really helpful for the undamped case (i.e., when $b=0$), but I am not sure how to proceed when $b>0$.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures I meant to say post, not email